How does C++ choose between ambiguous templates here?
I was reading about template type deduction in Effective Modern C++ and I think I understand how the compiler determines if a template matches, and what the deduced type should be, but I don't understand how the compiler chooses between matching overloads.
Consider this example:
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void hello(T& a) {
    std::cout << "Hello World 1" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void hello(const T& a) {
    std::cout << "Hello World 2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int x = 6;
    const int y = 5;
    int& z = x;

    hello(x);
    hello(y);
    hello(z);
}

This gives the following output:
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
Hello World 1

Intuitively I can see that the compiler selected the const overload when the input value was const which seems to make sense, but I was expecting it to throw an error due to the ambiguity. In particular, if we remove either version of the hello function the code still compiles and all the calls use the other one. This implies that the compiler has some way of selecting which template is preferable in this scenario to avoid the ambiguity.
I found this excellent explanation What is the partial ordering procedure in template deduction, but I am confused applying it to this scenario. In particular following the process outlined in the answer to that question implies that there is an ordering on the templates themselves which determines which one is "more specialised" and therefore will always be favoured, no matter the input argument. This is at odds with the fact that in my example the compiler made 2 different choices depending on the input type.

Another explanation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template

Just because A is favored over B doesn't mean that you always pick A. You might favor vanilla over chocolate, but if the store doesn't have any vanilla, then you will get the chocolate. You're not going to pick something that isn't available. In the cases for x and z, the const version is not available.

@RaymondChen Agreed, but why is the const version not available? If you comment out the non const version the code still compiles which implies X and Z do match against the const version.

Oops, I got it backward. The non-const version is unavailable to y, so it is forced to choose the const version. Both versions are available to x and z, and the non-const version is preferred.

First template's function void(int&) can be matched against void(const int&), but not other way around, therefore it's more specialized so for hello(x) it's the favorite choice.
For same reason void(const int&) is the only match for hello(y).
The call hello(z) is no different from hello(x) in this context. Reference would be "discarded".

Oh I see. That makes sense. Thank you. I guess I was thinking const int& would match int& when you pass an argument but the rules for this "matching" in specialisation are slightly different to the rules for passing an argument?

@starswap yes, deduction of type is different from choosing overloaded function and process of binding argument to parameter. For overloaded function both versions already exist and you can bind x to both const and non-const. That's ambigous. Template determines which cat, er, function exists in the box. That can be ambigous only if they overlap perfectly (why there are two alive cats?) There is std::size overload for arrays which illustrates how a template function is different from a function.

Thanks to the other answers and comments (and the question I linked as a duplicate) I think I managed to wrap my head around this, but I think it might be worth stating where my misconceptions were for the benefit of future readers:
Firstly, this problem isn't only to do with template deduction. It's also to do with overload resolution and implicit "cv-qualifying conversions".
I think this is the right way of thinking about it:

For x and z we can instantiate either template with T = int but if we want to call the second overload the compiler needs to implicitly convert the argument from int & to const int&. This is a standard "qualifying conversion" but as the first overload requires no conversion, the compiler prefers it for x and z. Trying this without the templates reveals the same result - the overload selected is the non-const one, which shows this part is to do with overload resolution and not template type deduction.
For y, we can instantiate the first overload with T = const int or the second one with T = int. Neither require addition of const and both have the same resulting type const int& for the parameter. The first overload is preferred because it's a more specific template match, as explained by @Swift and @RaymondChen. The preference ordering of templates can't use implicit conversions.

I'll leave the other answer as accepted since I think it helped me to get to the bottom of this, and please feel free to correct this answer if I'm still confused.
Additional sources:

Overloading reference vs const reference (both answers)
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution
https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/lvalues-rvalues-and-references/

